# Extract .scss to css using webpack

Tags: node.js, sass, webpack

I am trying to compile all my sass files in to a single style.css file as explained [Here](http://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2015/05/15/howto-setup-webpack-on-es6-react-application-with-sass.html) . I install my `npm install --save-dev extract-text-webpack-plugin` and in my webpack.config.dev.js is below.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: [
        './src',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({ title: 'My Project Build' }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('public/style.css', {
            allChunks: true,
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        }, {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass'),
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'public/sass'),
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        }],
    },
};
```

In my public folder , i added another folder `sass` and a single body.scss file for testing below.

```
.first-component {
    .text { font-size: 1.4rem; }
    .button { font-size: 1.7rem; }
}
```

when i run node server.js i was expecting my body.scss to me written in my empty style.css. My server.js is below.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('./webpack.config.dev');

const app = express();
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'))
);


app.listen(3030, 'localhost', err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3030');
});
```

My webpack is executed on node server.js . However, My style.css file still remains empty. I try everything to no avail . Please what am i missing and how do i address this?

Comment: Have you tried a standalone build? *webpack-dev-server* runs in-memory so you shouldn't see any files then. `ExtractTextPlugin` is something you don't want to use then anyway (production usage only).

Comment: @bebraw by standalone build , do you mean like webpack -p ? I did tried that but it fails.

Comment: It does not create the style.css file. Even when i create one for it, It does not create the suppose styling inside.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have set it up correctly? You'll want to skip HMR bits etc. for production. Here's [my setup](http://survivejs.com/webpack/building-with-webpack/separating-css/).

Comment: Instead of `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass')` you probably meant something like `ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')`.

Comment: @bebraw i have tried that sir. It didn't work.

Comment: Ok, hard to say what's going on then.

Comment: I don't see how you refer to your SCSS file. As long as you have a `require` somewhere (or direct `entry`), webpack should definitely pick it up. But based on the current information I cannot tell for sure.